# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Reinstallation Caused System to Freeze Before Login

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

Here are some specs before I begin:

- x86_64 architecture
- Intel Core i7-4790K processor
- **Nvidia GeForce GTX 960 graphics card**

For context, I was previously using Ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS, but due to a failed installation of an Nvidia graphics driver, I encountered recurring issues with the aspect ratio and booting the system up. I managed to get the system working properly several times, but each time these problems would resurface unprompted. I decided to give in and reinstall Linux with a USB I had (same version).

Reinstallation appeared to go fine. The aspect ratio looked good until I was prompted to restart my system before changes could be saved. Once I did that, Ubuntu would not start correctly, always freezing with either a black screen w/ a mouse in the bottom right corner, or an improperly-cropped login screen.

I can only start my system by accessing the GRUB menu (v 2.04) and selecting a less recent Linux kernel (5.11.0-27 rather than 5.11.0-41). The aspect ratio is still messed up, however.

Here are some of the things I've already tried:

- Editing my startup with "nomodeset" still results in a frozen login
- Navigating the 5.11.0-41 recovery mode menu freezes the system
- Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F4 during startup brings up the login prompt for a split second, but then ignores it and freezes on a black screen with a mouse in the bottom right corner
- Yes, I updated / upgraded everything
- "Additional Drivers" has locked me into the "Continue using a manually installed driver" option. I can't select any of the other options, like the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau open-source one, or the nvidia-driver-495 proprietary one. I'm concerned that if I attempt to manually install one, I'll end up with the same problems as last time!

Here is my output for `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM206 [GeForce GTX 960]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

When I tried `nvidia-smi` I got `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`.

Any help would be appreciated. I believe the mistakes I made previously included editing blacklists and trying to reinstall vital packages...so needless to say, I'd like to avoid those methods if possible.